# dokuwiki leverage http cache header

Tags: http-caching, dokuwiki

I need to make a dokuwiki content cachable by an http client.
I've searched in the doc. and in the plugin list and found nothing about this behaviour.

Do you know if it exists?

Comment: Can you describe desired behavior more precisely? What is "http client" here?

Comment: I want to leverage http caching headers (ie : etag/304) I think that it should be easy and expected it to be implemented by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the maintainer of DokuWiki in https://www.freelists.org/post/dokuwiki/HTTP-caching-confusion,2, DokuWiki makes use of PHP session to do CSRF prevention and breadcrumbs. Once a page is session dependent, it can no longer be cached by PHP's default header output.

However, You can write a plugin yourself of course.